# Distintos formatos a fecha

Tags: r

Tengo un df de este estilo, con fechas en formato "fecha" y en formato "numérico":

```
    df <- read.table(text = '
    col1        col2        col3    col4
    NA           NA           NA    45535
    31/08/2024  31/08/2024  45535   45535
    31/08/2024  NA          45535   45535
    31/08/2024  NA          45535   45535
    31/08/2024  31/08/2024  45535   45535
    31/08/2024  31/08/2024  45535   45535
    31/08/2024  31/08/2024  45535   45535
    31/08/2024  31/08/2024  45535   45535
    31/08/2024  31/08/2024  45535   45535',
header = TRUE, colClasses = "character",stringsAsFactors = FALSE, na.strings = 'NA')
```

Los datos siempre vienen en formato character y no sé de antemano que columna va a ser fecha y cual numérico.

Estoy buscando la forma de pasarlo todo a formato fecha.

Si aplico  `as.Date` los datos que vienen como número se convierten en NA. (col3, col4)

Si lo paso a numérico y luego a fecha, ahora son los que tienen formato fecha los que pasan a NA.

Podría decir que cuente el número de caracteres de los datos de la segunda fila y si tiene 5 que los pase a un formato y el resto a otro. Pero si me llega otro fichero donde en esa segunda fila hay un NA ya no sabe si tiene 5 caracteres y me da error.

Tampoco me ha servido cambiar los NA por algún valor, hacer la transformación de las fechas y luego quitar el valor por NA.

Seguramente en sencillo pero no doy con la tecla.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta es otra aproximación:

```
to_date <- function(x) {
  suppressWarnings({
     d <- as.Date(as.numeric(x), origin = "1899-12-30")
     if (all(is.na(d))) {
      d <- as.Date(x, format = "%d/%m/%Y")
     }
  })
 d
}
```

Simplemente si falla un criterio de conversión probamos el otro. El `suppressWarnings()` es estético y se puede obviar, es solo para no ver los warnings por las conversiones que sabemos de antemano van a fallar.

La aplicación a todo el `Data.Frame` puede hacerse así:

```
as.data.frame(lapply(df, to_date))
```

Answer (score 0):

Una alternativa para esto puede ser creando una función que identifique primero el tipo de dato en una columna, y luego aplicar el cambio de formato de fechas. En este caso, acá hay un ejemplo de una función que identifica que columnas tienen este char "/" y aplica el reformato de fechas, y lo mismo para el resto de las otras columnas. En este caso la función no altera los NA, por lo que quedan igual.

```
convert_to_date <- function(data) {
  for (col in names(data)) {
    if (any(grepl("/", data[[col]], fixed = TRUE))) {
      data[[col]] <- as.Date(data[[col]], format = "%d/%m/%Y")
    } else if (any(!grepl("/", data[[col]], fixed = TRUE))) {
      data[[col]] <- as.Date(as.numeric(data[[col]]), origin = "1899-12-30")
    }
  }
  return(data)
}

# Aplicamos la función sobre la data:
data |> convert_to_date()

# Resultado:
        col1       col2       col3       col4
1       <NA>       <NA>       <NA> 2024-08-31
2 2024-08-31 2024-08-31 2024-08-31 2024-08-31
3 2024-08-31       <NA> 2024-08-31 2024-08-31
4 2024-08-31       <NA> 2024-08-31 2024-08-31
5 2024-08-31 2024-08-31 2024-08-31 2024-08-31
6 2024-08-31 2024-08-31 2024-08-31 2024-08-31
7 2024-08-31 2024-08-31 2024-08-31 2024-08-31
8 2024-08-31 2024-08-31 2024-08-31 2024-08-31
9 2024-08-31 2024-08-31 2024-08-31 2024-08-31
```